# Block a IP range via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ip, range, block

I want to block huge IP range of a country, I want to ask which method is correct to use in htaccess.

1. (This is Mintify)

   ```
   deny from 1.80.0.0/13 1.92.0.0/14 1.192.0.0/13 1.202.0.0/15 1.204.0.0/14 14.144.0.0/12 14.208.0.0/12 23.80.54.0/24 23.104.141.0/24 23.105.14.0/24
   ```
2. (This is regular)

   ```
   deny from 109.105.128.0/20
   deny from 109.105.144.0/21
   deny from 109.105.159.0/18
   deny from 109.105.161.0/19
   ```

Do both format work?

Answer (score 0):

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html

> `Deny from all|host|env=[!]env-variable [host|env=[!]env-variable] ...`

Either method can be used, the `...` means you can have more of those arguments. Which one you choose to use depends on how readable you want it to be or how you want to organize the list of IP blocks.

Comment: I am newbie, I want to know, I am using first method (Mintify) which I given above is correct or wrong ?